# MiKTeX 2.9 Console

Tags: miktex2.9

I had cause recently to re-install MiKTeX 2.9 and notice the addition of the `MiKTeX Console` which makes checking for `loaded packages` and `package updating` a lot clearer. In my previous installation packages were loaded and updated in either `User` or `Admin` mode. Am I correct in assuming that this distinction has now disappeared? My installation is for `private use`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is still a distinction.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Having no urgent need for a system-wide installation I installed `MiKTeX for private use` to keep things simple. Sadly, also don't study tutorials unless absolutely unavoidable. Also want to point out that the `private use` installation will not show the full detail of what is available in the `console` for a `system-wide` installation.